# Calling RestAPI RestSharp GET method with parameters in C#

Tags: c#, api, post, get, restsharp

It is probably really easy to solve, but I am struggling with it a lot.

I am connected to API using RestSharp - everything is working fine, but I do not know how to pass parameters to a method 'couse they are in a weird format (at least for me, I am newbie :)).

Te method's parameter should look like that:

```
"order_id": 123456
```

http://api.baselinker.com - API documentation

My testing code:

```
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var client = new RestClient("https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php");
string token = "********************";


RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

var parameter = ;

request.AddParameter("token", token);
request.AddParameter("method", "getOrders");
request.AddParameter("parameters", "order_id": 123456);



var response = await client.PostAsync(request);

Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Of course this line is getting error 'cause VS is expecting ','

```
request.AddParameter("parameters", "order_id": 123456);
```

EDIT: Passing parameter as a string also doesn't work:

```
request.AddParameter("parameters", @"""order_id"": 123456");
```

What is the proper way to do it? Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it what you want?

```
request.AddJsonBody(
    new 
    {
      "order_id": 123456
    }); // AddJsonBody serializes the object automatically
```

or another way to write:

```
request.AddParameter(
   "application/json",
   "{ \"order_id\": 123456 }", // <- your JSON string
   ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I really do not know how to use your first method, but the other one worked exactly as I wanted ;)

Comment: @ŚwiętopełZiemowit glad to help dont forget to close your question by validating/upvoting the answer